# Why not assign multiple types in an ElasticSearch index for logging, rather than multiple indices?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I am currently researching some data storage strategies with ElasticSearch and wonder why for storing logs, [this page](http://A%20standard%20format%20is%20to%20assign%20a%20new%20index%20for%20each%20day.) indicates:

> A standard format is to assign a new index for each day.

Would it not make more sense to create an index (database) with a new type a name (table) per day?

I am looking at this from the point of view of each index is tied to a different web application.

In another scenario, a web app uses one index. One of the types within that index is used for logging (what we currently do with SQL Server).  Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting idea and, yes, you could probably do that.  Why use multiple indices instead?  If having control over things like shard-to-node allocation (maybe you want all of 2015 stored on one set of nodes, 2014, another), filter cache size, and similar is important, you lose that by going to a single index/multi-mapping approach.  For very high volume applications, that control might be significant. YMMV.

With regard to the "each index is tied to a different web application" sentiment, aliases can (and are) used to collect multiple physical indices under a single searchable umbrella; you create one index per day/week/whatever, say, *logs-20150730, logs-20150731...* and assign the *logs* alias to all of the indices in the series.  Net effect is the same as having a single "index".

Nice part of the alias approach is that purging/pruning old data is trivial; just delete the index when its contents age out of whatever your data retention policy is.  With multi-mappings, you'd have to delete the requisite mapping within the index  (do-able, but pretty I/O intrusive, since you'd likely be shoving stuff around inside every shard the mapping was distributed through.)

Comment: So in a web application scenario where users have projects that collect a lot of data,, you could have one index for users, their profiles, etc., then create multiple indices with one ProjectData type containing each day's project data for all users. If we only wanted to keep say three months of data at any given time, purging is simple. However what of different users had varying purge dates? How does this approach sound? Why not just create new ProjectData types within the same index?and